# Mount filesystem for a specific user at user login

Tags: ext4, automount

I want to mount 2 existing ext4 filesystems for a specific user when the user logs in and ensure that they are dismounted when the user logs off. I am running on Ubuntu 22.04. The suggestions that I found are all 10+ years old and I have been unable to get them to work.
The filesystems are currently being mounted from /etc/fstab but in a way that makes them accessible to all users and I only want one user to be able to mount and access them.

Comment: Continue to mount them via `/etc/fstab`, but mount them somewhere only `specific_user` can access. Read `man fstab`.

Comment: This does part of what I want but the filesystems remain mounted after the user logs out. I would like a solution where no other user could mount these filesystems and where they would become unmounted when the owning user logs out.

Comment: If only the intended user can access the mountpoint, and if only root can mount the filesystem (`nouser`, a default setting), then does unmounting when that user logs out matter? How would anyone else be able to access that filesystem if it's mounted at a point that is inaccessible to them, and if they don't themselves have the rights to mount it?